Dates of Use in Commerce to Renew a Trademark
If I have a U.S. trademark for which a Sections 8 and 9 needs to be filed on May 22, 2024, I understand that the mark must be in use at least during the year prior (May 22, 2023 - May 22, 2024).  However, if I file for the Sections 8 and 9 on the last day of the six month grace period, does that extend the dates of use? So, it would be May 22, 2023 - November 22, 2024, or must use still occur from May 22, 2023 - May 22, 2024?

You are supposed to be using it the whole time. Did you stop at some point?
